# Bash delete directories containing certain files

Tags: bash, find, delete-directory

Given a directory structure like

```
parent
  - child1
    - file1
    - file2
    - file3
  - child2
    - file1
    - file3
  - child3
    - file1
    - file2
    - file3
    - file4
```

what command will delete all child directories of `parent` that contain all or some of `file1`, `file2`, `file3` but no others. I.e. in the example `child1` and `child2` should be deleted but `child3` should remain since it also contains `file4`.

Please post both a dry run and actual version of the command to first check which folders would be deleted.

Comment: Your question is unclear and your sentances contradict each other

Comment: @VojinPurić How so?

Comment: sounds like a homework assignment and if so ... SO isn't here to provide answers to homework questions; you are expected to show what efforts (ie, coding) have been attempted and if there are specific technical/coding issue then perhaps we can assist with understanding the issue and help find a solution; please review [how do I ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) then come back and update the question accordingly, in particular, show us what code you've tried so far, the (wrong) output from your code, and the (correct) expected output

Comment: @markp-fuso You got this sort of stuff for homework? I'm doing research. No more homework for me. As for my own efforts, I have a Python solution but wanted to learn how to do this in bash directly. Fiddled around with `find` for a while but didn't manage to get it working. Feel free to help if you can otherwise I'd recommend being slower with your assumptions.

Comment: Please add to your question (no comment): What have you searched for, and what did you find? What have you tried, and how did it fail?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would probably need a function that deletes the child directories only if it does not contain a set of input file(s) you want to check for.

```
#!/bin/bash
delete_dir() {
    local subdir=$1
    local string_of_files=$2

    #convert list of files into array
    IFS=','
    read -ra files_to_keep <<< "$string_of_files"

    local list_of_files=()
    if [ -d "$subdir" ]; then
        for i in $subdir/*; do list_of_files=("${list_of_files[@]}" $(basename $i)); done

        local list_of_matched_files=()
        for i in ${list_of_files[@]}; do
            if [[ " ${files_to_keep[@]} " =~ " $i " ]]; then
               list_of_matched_files=("${list_of_matched_files[@]}" "$i")
            fi
        done

        if [ "${#list_of_matched_files[@]}" -eq 0 ]; then
            echo "deleting $subdir"
            #rm -r $subdir
        else
            echo "Not deleting $subdir, since it contains files you want to keep!!"
        fi
    else
        echo "directory $subdir not found"
    fi
    }

# Example1: function call
delete_dir child1 file4

# Example2: For your case you can loop through subdirectories like,
for dir in $(ls -d parent/child*); do
    delete_dir $dir file4
done
```

example output:

```
$ ./test.sh
Not deleting child1/, since it contains files you want to keep!!
Not deleting child2/, since it contains files you want to keep!!
deleting child3/
```

You'd be better off using python for such operations if you're are at liberty to choose, since you can make it much simpler and modular.

Comment: `for dir in $(ls -d parent/child*)` is hurting me

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the parent directory only contains child folders, this one-liner would list the folders containing only files on the marked for deletion list:

```
for child in *; do if [ "$(ls -1 $child | egrep -v '(file1|file2|file3)'|wc -l)" -eq "0" ]; then echo "would delete $child"; fi ; done
```

This one line command would delete them:

```
for child in *; do if [ "$(ls -1 $child | egrep -v '(file1|file2|file3)'|wc -l)" -eq "0" ]; then rm -rf $child; fi ; done
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you want? Loops through the files in parent directory and deletes them if the resulting file path doesn't contain file4

this shows the files that will be deleted

```
while IFS= read -r -d $'\0' f; do
  if [[ "$f" =~ 'file4' ]]; then
    continue;
  else
    echo "rm "$f""
  fi
done < <(find parent -type f -print0)
```

this deletes them

```
while IFS= read -r -d $'\0' f; do
  if [[ "$f" =~ 'file4' ]]; then
    continue;
  else
    rm "$f"
  fi
done < <(find parent -type f -print0)
```

Comment: I misread the question, I thought you meant delete all files except for file4